# how to create a login on php without database ?

Tags: php, authentication

i want create a login on my web site in PHP without Database because i don't have an installed database on my server. Which approach i need to use ?

I just think about write the user on file

> `txt or csv`

Comment: Is `SQLite` not an option?

Comment: If your planning on using 1 user, then store the username and password in variables. Multiple users, use a database... or a method which will not have the potential to compromise passwords/other sensitive data which should belong in a Database... and 2 upvotes for this question? Which lacks understanding, research & a poorly structured question? Jesus

Comment: Really now, who upvotes this? There's no exact shortage of [duplicates](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20login%20without%20database)

Comment: I can't install an DB , but i need trace the users on my site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a simple xml file to save the pass and login,
or use a NOSQL that you don't need to install it

Comment: Unfortunatly, this should belong as a comment. It is not answer material, i would recommend updating this to earn yourself enough reputation to comment